# Dynamic role value in Spring @PostAuthorize annotation

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I have gameId path variable setted in the URL of a REST web service and I wan't to give permission to the user who has paticular role on particular game table, Whene user login, I create authorities by concatenat roles with gameId, I have try this but it doesn't work :

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_GAMER_'+#gameId)")
```

Comment: @CIPHER007 one at least with one role at least

Comment: you can use authorisation with more than one role like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_GAMER_1') or hasRole('ROLE_GAMER_2')")` . Is it meet your requirement.

Comment: @CIPHER007 it can work with hard coded gameId but not with #gameId expression

Comment: `'ROLE_GAMER_' + #gameId` is a Spring Expression. `hasRole` does not support Spring Expressions. This is not documented anywhere explicitly, but is clear [from the source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.java#L74).

Comment: @MK-rou did you added `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

Comment: @AjitSoman I will check it later, I'm not at work today

Comment: @manish I think you are wrong on this one; the expression is evaluated before the method is invoked.

Comment: As mentioned by holmis83, it's work very well, the problem come from that I have missed @PathVariable for gameId variable in the method signature

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by holmis83, it's work very well, the problem come from that I have missed @PathVariable for gameId variable in the method signature